# POST contentType always shows text/plain even though content is XML

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-karaf

I am working on a `RESTful` application using `Apache Karaf, OSGi, JPA, JAX-RS & JAX-B.`

While doing the `POST` operation I am facing a issue where in I am always getting the `contentType as text/plain` in the logs while I am sending `APPLICATION_XML`.

Here are the **logs** below:

```
2013-12-24 21:20:55,070 | WARN  | qtp5394449-132   | JAXRSUtils                       | 178 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 2.7.4 | No operation matching request path "/cxf/rest/customers" is found, Relative Path: /, HTTP Method: POST, ContentType: text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Accept: */*,.
2013-12-24 21:20:55,073 | WARN  | qtp5394449-132   | WebApplicationExceptionMapper    | 178 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs - 2.7.4 | javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:202)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
    at Proxy87766e5a_eb08_4d8e_b5a1_dece05a1b0ff.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:943)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I tried other operations such as `GET`, `DELETE` which are able to call the subsequent function correctly but I can't seem to send the `POST` and it shows this issue every time.

Can anyone plz help me here?

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the Content-Type header correctly on your POST request? Have you sent your request through an HTTP recording proxy (such as Charles Proxy, but there are many others) to verify this? Show the applicable parts of your Client and Server code as well.

Comment: @Charlie I am using google chrome's POSTMAN as restful client and yes I have set the content type as XML in it and sent xml content in the message.

Comment: If you sent your request through a recording proxy, you would be able to see that that selecting "XML" doesn't actually set the Content-Type header on your request properly, leaving it as 'Content-Type text/plain;charset=UTF-8'. You need to explicitly add a Header (headers button on the right), the Header of course is Content-Type and the value to be the appropriate MIME type.

Comment: @Charlie Oh yes!! I am able to send the message now correctly. Thanks so much, You saved my day!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments and doing a bit more research on PostMan's development.

The [simple extension version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) does not currently default the Content-Type of the request based on the dropdown in associated to the raw post body header. You need to instead the Content-Type explicitly using a header explicitly.

Looking on Postman's Github, it seems this is [not a new bug](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/issues/327). Digging through issues, it seems that there is also a [Packaged App version of Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-packa/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) which behaves properly, and gives you distinct options for `XML (application/xml)` and `XML (text/xml)` even.